# Capturing WLST output in Java Client

Tags: java, wlst

I am presently invoking WLST from a Java Client. I would like to return the result of the WLST function back to my Java Client. I was hoping if someone could help me.

Regards,
Sarat Challa

Answer (score 1):

Consider http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/using_WLST.html#wp1094015 to redirect WLST/Jython output to a file. Write anything you like into that file, then read from your Java caller.

Also, directly reading the STDOUT of the WLST executor should be possible, depending on how you call that from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Sarat, Not really clear about - What is this Java client? is it a jsp/servlet or normal java program? Java supports logger. You can refer to

> Log4j

framework within the Java programs.